# How to use if condition to hide element in Smarty template (TYPO3)?

Tags: templates, if-statement, typo3, smarty, conditional-statements

TYPO3 website is using TYPO3 extension of Smarty.
In one existing template called header.tpl I have this code:

```
<div class="header">
...
</div>
<div class="nav">
...
</div>
```

Is there some way to hide div element with the class "nav" using if condition? This header.tpl is used on every page, but I want to achieve that only on page with id=3 (in TYPO3) the navigation part will be hidden.

For example:

```
<div class="header">
...
</div>
{if (???) }
<div class="nav">
...
</div>
{/if}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please share more information about that setup. Basically TYPO3 is using "Fluid" (https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid) as templating engine. If really "Smarty" is being used, it seems to be a very special setup which is not standard TYPO3...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TYPO3 extension of Smarty, there are special plugins that give you the possibility to access data from TYPO3.
You can find them here: https://github.com/rtp-ch/smarty/tree/master/Classes/SmartyPlugins/Frontend

I'd say to use `{if $data.uid == 3}`, but I also need to see more of your setup to be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you need to see more of my setup?

Comment: The code where Smarty is instantiated and what variables are assigned.